# Haskell Bindable entities?

Tags: haskell, theory

I saw that, in the book, Programming Language Design Concepts by John Wiley, 2004, there is a definition for bindables:

> "A bindable entity is one that may be bound to an identifier.
>   Programming languages vary in the kinds of entity that are bindable:
>
> • C’s bindable entities are types, variables, and function procedures.
>
> • JAVA’s bindable entities are values, local variables, instance and
>   class variables, methods, classes, and packages.
>
> • ADA’s bindable entities include types, values, variables,
>   procedures, exceptions, packages, and tasks."

I'm curious, which bindable entities are in Haskell?

Comment: N.B. functions are values in Haskell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haskell has three namespaces, one each for runtime computations, types, and modules.

Any term representing a runtime computation may be named in the computation namespace. `data` and `newtype` declarations create new names in the computation namespace for constructing values of their new type and, if record syntax is used, for selecting fields from the new type. `class` declarations create new names in the computation namespace for their methods.

Any monomorphic type may be named in the type namespace with a `type` declaration (see comments below for my predictions on confusing subtleties in this statement). `data` and `newtype` declarations create new names in the type namespace for constructing the type they declare. `class` declarations create new names in the type namespace for the constraint they create.

`module` declarations create new names in the module namespace.

GHC extends Haskell, adding a variety of new ways to bind names (almost all in the type namespace); a comprehensive list is probably too large for this format but [the manual](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/) is excellent and covers them all.

Now, to the subtleties of `type`. One confusion that I predict will arise is this: I say only monomorphic types may be named. But one may object that I can certainly write, e.g.

```
type TypeOfIdMono a = a -> a
id :: TypeOfIdMono a
```

and that looks like it has named a polymorphic type. I claim that Haskell's penchant for making `forall`s implicit has instead confused the issue, and that `TypeOfId a` is in fact monomorphic. With explicit foralls, this has been written:

```
type TypeOfIdMono a = a -> a
id :: forall a. TypeOfIdMono a
```

That is: we have not actually named `id`'s type here, but rather the type of a monomorphic function which only operates on `a`s. `id` says additionally that the caller gets to choose `a` -- that is, that the function is polymorphic. Compare this declaration, which is not allowed in standard Haskell (though is available via GHC extensions, as alluded to above):

```
type TypeOfIdPoly = forall a. a -> a
id :: TypeOfIdPoly
```

Here we really have named a polymorphic type.

In short: one can and should distinguish between three orthogonal concepts: "parameterized types" (e.g. `TypeOfIdMono` which expects an additional argument), types which mention a type variable (e.g. `TypeOfIdMono a`), and polymorphic types (e.g. `TypeOfIdPoly`) which necessarily have a `forall`.